# Cron Job gives an error msg for arguments

Tags: php, cron, phplist

I am using phplist on hostgator and trying to setup a cron job to send campaign automatically.

I have created a cron job but it may gives an error:

```
/opt/php55/lib/php -q/home4/username/public_html/domain.com/admin/index.php -p=processqueue -c/home4/username/public_html/domain.com/config/config.php
```

But It's give an error msg:

> /bin/sh: /opt/php55/lib/php: is a directory

How can make it workable?

Thanks and hope to get solution as soon.

Comment: Find where is your php binary. It's obviously not in the path provided.

Comment: php binary means?

Comment: A file called php

Comment: @u_mulder Is php.ini or any other please give me some hint